# SQL SERVER error Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "xxxxxxx"

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

In SQL server 2016 I've created a linked server from another SQL server
I made a view looking for data in che DB of linked server.
From SSMS or from my app the view fail to retrive data first time, if I repeat same view a second time it works fine.
I noticed if I leave idle for 10 minutes, when I repeat to run the view first time it fail but from the second time onwards it works fine.

Running first time the view I get the error:
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "MY_LINKED_SERVER"
If I run the view immediately after (second time) it works fine...
Is it something reguarding keep alive parameters?